# OAuth2 Resource Server not authenticating requests

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am setting up a standalone OAuth2 Resource Server and it does not appear to be authenticating requests, using CURL calls without a bearer token seem to succeed anyway.  Alternatively, I tried to set up Global Method Security and all requests get rejected with the error

`An authentication object could not be found in the current security context`

even if `@PreAuthorize('submitAll()')` is set on the request in question.  I'm happy to take either path to getting authentication to work (method level security or a correct configuration that will inspect tokens).

Here is the code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setClientId("commsuite");
        tokenServices.setClientSecret("secret");
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:10386/oauth/check_token");
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        final OAuth2AuthenticationManager oAuth2AuthenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenService());
        return oAuth2AuthenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenServices(tokenService()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager());
}

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .antMatcher("/api/2/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}

/* Here is the api controller code with the call */
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"text/plain"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody
String testEndpoint() {

    return "Gnarly Dudes\n";
}
```

In this case, a raw curl call with no bearer token succeeds.

As a second case, I tried using Method Level security annotations by adding the following code and then adding `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` to the `testEndpoint` method above.  In this case, I get the `Authentication object could not be found` error both in a raw CURL call and also using a call with a valid bearer token obtained from a separate authentication server.  I suspect I'm missing something along the line. Thanks...

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me after adding

`public class AppSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}`

Empty class just the extend to enable spring security